# Linq and EF4, Inner join conditional statement

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4

```
OrdersRepository ordersRepository = new OrdersRepository();

var productInQuery = ordersRepository.ProductIn;
var orderInfoQuery = ordersRepository.OrderInfo;


var result = (from p in productInQuery
              from o in orderInfoQuery
              where p.refNo == o.refNo
              select new {
                 t1 = p.no,
                 t2 = o.no}).ToArray();
```

I wrote like above code for inner join. and I want to **add some conditional statement for OrderInfo context**.

```
...

if(orderDate != DateTime.MinValue){
   orderInfoQuery = orderInfoQuery.Where(x => x.orderDate == orderDate); 
}

// also I tried this too. no is integer in Mysql and I'm sure there is 222 value.
// but still it return always null...
orderInfoQuery = orderInfoQuery.Where(x => x.no == 222);



var result = (from p in productInQuery
                  from o in orderInfoQuery
                  where p.refNo == o.refNo
                  select new {
                     t1 = p.no,
                     t2 = o.no}).ToArray();
```

I add the conditional statement but **it return always null**. (I check DB(Mysql) value is existed)

And is it not **inner join**?

```
var result = (from p in productInQuery
              join o in orderInfoQuery on p.refNo equals o.refNo
              select new {
                 t1 = p.no,
                 t2 = o.no}).ToArray();
```

Any body know this, please advice me~

Thank you!

[EDIT]

OMG, I'm so sorry, the productIn and orderInfo is never matched. that's why it return always null.

May I ask question again please,

```
var result = (from p in productInQuery
  join o in orderInfoQuery on p.refNo equals o.refNo
  join x in productQuery on p.productNo equals x.no
  join t in productOutQuery on p.no equals t.productInNo into productIn
  from t in productIn.DefaultIfEmpty()
  orderby o.processDate descending
  select new
  {
      qty = p.qty,
      dateIn = o.processDate,
      dateOut = (DateTime?)(from m in orderInfoQuery where m.refNo == t.refNo select m.processDate).FirstOrDefault(),
      etaDate = (DateTime?)(from w in orderInfoQuery where w.refNo == t.refNo select w.eta).FirstOrDefault(),  
  }).ToArray();
```

this is my linq code, and I want to search by etaDate now.

how can I write linq code. In above code, the etaDate is just sub query. and I want to get

the date that etaDate is exactly matched with specific date.

could you help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: `.Where(x => x.orderDate = orderDate);` should be `.Where(x => x.orderDate == orderDate);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to make sure that the types between the two dates here:

```
orderDate != DateTime.MinValue
```

and here:

```
x.orderDate == orderDate
```

are in the same date format. If one value has a different format or adds extra precision, then the conditional will always fail.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I think it is not format problem. I change the code to search the other field that integer but still return null always.

Comment: And your join works when you do not include the where method? Like there is a resulting match between your productInQuery and orderInQuery? If there is, see if you can put the where clause in your linq join: "where o.no == 222"

Comment: yes, you are right. the data couldn't be matched. could you review my edited question again please? Thank you very much for your valuable time!

Comment: Since you are using entity framework, why don't you create a view with all your joins, and then do a linq on that? This would confuse you less with linq code. Plus I'd extract the queries out of the select statement since you are doing a join on two tables twice (which would cause a performance issue). Do it before the linq statement and pass into a variable for code reusability, which will set up for your question; use that variable to pass into a where clause where "etaData = valueReturned from (DateTime?)(from w in orderInfoQuery where w.refNo == t.refNo select w.eta).FirstOrDefault()"

Comment: But if I were you, I'd create another question instead of appending to this one, then you'd get more help and probably more useful answers :) I also do get bummed out if I don't get positive feedback to help my ratings..